# overflow: hidden doesn't trigger in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

My container should bring up a scroll bar when there is an overflow. It doesn't show any scroll bar when it is not full. I have used "overflow: hidden" for this. It works fine in chrome and mozilla but it is not happening in **IE8**. I see that the overflow action is not being triggered.

html:

```
<div class="myBlock" style="overflow:hidden; outline:none;">...</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myBlock {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 349px;
}
```

I need a scroll bar only on the y axis when my container overflows. Please let me know if i am missing out something. And also i'm getting the scroll bar in IE8 if i resize the window. This is a weird behavior and there is no resize functionality in my code.

Comment: `overflow-y: scroll;` should be `overflow-y: scroll !important;` instead. Try it.

Comment: I have tried making it !important..but nothing changed

Comment: Now that is weird. But to be honest, that is the only thing I can come up with. Try looking some ways of triggering "hasLayout" on google. And try removing that `overflow:hidden;`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a little more information on the `myBlock` class?

Is your element absolutely positioned? If so, try changing it to relative and see if that fixes the issue - There is a weird IE8 quirk that could be fixed by applying `position: relative`.

Also, try using `overflow: auto`. This is the actual property you should set for showing the horizontol/veritcal scroll bar when necessary, otherwise hiding it.

EDIT:

Try setting your `overflow-y` style to `overflow-y: scroll !important`. This will ensure it takes precedence over your other overflow style. You can also set `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` separately to get the desired affect, why seems less hacky to me.

Comment: I have made the position:relative but it doesnt seem to work for me. myBlock has height of 349px and 7 elements fit in to that. As soon as 7th element is hit, then the scroll bar should appear.

Comment: overflow:auto is creating a slide space in my block in IE8 though there is no scroll. All i want a scroll on overflow. And also Im using Jquery nicescroll for scrolling actions. It is already appended to that div element just to show nicescroll instead of native scrollbar